Bathroom wall, painted CMU, drywall, and tile meet. Add with drywall or skim coat?
the cmu wall in my bathroom meets drywall.
How should I proceed for a smooth finish?
3 “issues”:

Current wall isn’t perfectly level (see temporary baseboard)
How to handle it joining the tile
Cmu is painted, not sure how to prep or prime it for proper adhesion

please advise, am I on the right track in this thinking?
Option A:
1/4” moisture resistant drywall
But how to prep the cmu portion of the wall so it’s level with drywall portion.
Option B:
Skim coat everything? What is best for this situation, next to shower. stucco, joint compound or microcement?
I’m excited for some clarifying answers so that I can complete the wall and tile next… thank you in advance!
https://imgur.com/a/zOOoWz0

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"... so that I can complete the wall and tile next… "  Are you tiling the wall or just trying to make it smooth so the block lines are not noticeable?  There is a marked difference in the procedure depending on the desired result.   Just skim coat with drywall compound if not tiling.  If tiling, skim with thinset over the block lines . Then tile. If the tiles are large format. even skimming the lines is not needed, just tile.
